# Training CNN model using keras works with CPU but not with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a CNN model to classify simple images (squares and crosses) and everything works just fine when I use the cpu but when I use the gpu everything works until the training starts and i get this error:

2022-06-15 04:25:49.158944: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8401

And then the program just stops.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: That is not an error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I know this is not an error message but it is pretty much the only thing i get other than the creation of the device with the model of my gpu and the model summary. But i forgot a line, i get "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)" at the end but i couldn't find info on the meaning of the exit code.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by using an older version of Cuda and cuDNN.

Answer (score 2):

if you use pycharm, you can select the "Emulate terminal in output console" option to print detailed error information.

Run->Edit Configration->Execution ->Emulate terminal in output console

On windows, maybe CUDA is missing zlibwapi.dll file, and you can download it and  move it to bin of cuda.